# How to make browser to not put line break if font size is changed only by animation and not normal resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with centered text that has animation effect on hover event. Text size changes during animation and it's new size doesn't fit into container div width for only few pixels.

Here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qsL0pgej/

HTML:

```
<div class="clickable-container">
<a class="link"><span>Some text for demonstration</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clickable-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  color: white;

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@keyframes link-hover {
    from {font-size: 22px;}
    to {font-size: 27px;}
}

.link:hover {
    animation-name: link-hover;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

I don't want this weird behaviour when i move mouse over div. I want it to put line breaks only for initial font size. Is there any workaround? Any CSS, HTML or Javascript solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can animate by transforming the scale instead of changing the font size.

Example code:

```
@keyframes link-hover {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.22, 1.22);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.22, 1.22);
        transform: scale(1.22, 1.22);
    }
}
```

Since the new font size is `27` and the old font size is `22`, it is easy to calculate the desire scale ratio (`27 / 22 ~= 1.227`).

I put it in JSFiddle where you can test it: https://jsfiddle.net/0axqjnxo/